# How to play live stream with hls.js

Tags: javascript, live-streaming, iptv

I'm trying to make website that clients able to watch iptv.

I'm using [hls.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udpbG.png).
As a start I have try to play stream that broadcasting from vlc player. I also try to play the url https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8 and it's playing fine.

but when I try to play live stream I have failed.
showing below log on console

[image: Console log]

Also on network tab I can see it's downloading continuously.

[image: Network]